TALLY - Http api to export tally data of voucher master
I have tried exporting the  dependent masters of vouchers through http api using xml, to export it from tally. in these ways .I'am able to get stock items,ledgers,vouchers individually.but unable to get dependent masters through http api?? How can we export a schema of dependent masters through http request??
I tried below options.
For the first one i'am getting voucher data.
For the second one I'am getting voucher data.
But i need master if it
This is the request schema i used for it
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <EXPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>
                <STATICVARIABLES>
                    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                    <SVFROMDATE Type="Date">01-11-2024</SVFROMDATE>
                    <SVTODATE Type="Date">15-11-2024</SVTODATE>
                </STATICVARIABLES>
            </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA />
        </EXPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

Request - 2
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMCOLLECTION</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>

            <!-- VOUCHER Collection -->
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION 
                        ISMODIFY="No" 
                        ISFIXED="No" 
                        ISINITIALIZE="No" 
                        ISOPTION="No" 
                        ISINTERNAL="No" 
                        NAME="CUSTOMVOUCHERDATA">
                        <TYPE>VOUCHER</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>
                            VOUCHERNUMBER, DATE, PARTYNAME, AMOUNT, 
                            VCHSTATUSDATE, EFFECTIVEDATE, VOUCHERTYPENAME
                        </FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


Can i use alter id to get the data that is updated

Add <DBIncludeFamily>Yes</DBIncludeFamily> inside <STATICVARIABLES>

Can i use alter id to get the data that is updated

ask your query in detail in separate thread
